# how to get the website which embed the swf?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to know which website embed my swf file.
For example, my swf is www.a.com/a.swf, and www.b.com/index.html embed my swf. How I can get "www.b.com" in my code,when stage.loaderinfo.url just get "www.a.com/a.swf".

Comment: sounds like you want to get the HTTP referrer, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having a handler on your server for requests coming from your swf.  So, you could do something like (untested)

```
var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.domain.com/tracker");
var location: String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location");
request.data = new URLVariables("location=" + location)
loader.load(request)
```

Note, I am using a call out to javascript to get the current url.  Similarly you could use something like `location.host` instead of `window.location`.  There are others as well that javascript will provide.

Comment: That's a good idea. But ExternalInterface.call("window.location") return null.I don't know why

Comment: use ExternalInterface.call("function (){return window.location}") and get the value.Thank you.